# Can i send parameters with an ajax function call in an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have multiple buttons calling the same ajax function. I want to be able to pass the id of the button and have the ajax function act on another element relative to the button that called the function. Am I able to send a parameter with the call?
For eg button 1 calls the function but changes textbox 1, button 2 calls same function but changes textbox 2 etc

Comment: What did you tried?? Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters by url (get), or send them in request body( post ).
for example:

```
  var getId = 1;
  $.get("http://my.web.site/getaction/"+getId,function(result){
    console.log(result);
  });
  var jsondata = {key:"value"};
  $.post("http://my.web.site/postaction",jsondata ,function(result){
    console.log(result);
  });
```

when the parameter is simple and no need to encrypt, just simply use get.
when the parameter is complex or need to encrypt, like password, use post and send them in body.

Comment: Thank Loic for your attempt to help me. I don't want to change pages or url. i just want to send the parameter to the function so I know which button called it so it can then act on another html element with the same number. Buttons and textboxes all on one page. If button1 calls the function textbox1 changes. If button2 calls the function then textbox2 changes.I just want to pass the number ie 1 or 2 or 3 etc

Comment: @nevvyf, ajax won't change page or url, form submit do.

Comment: Thanks. But I have no idea how to implement what you have suggested.

Comment: What part of your code is showing which button was pressed? Which part of your code is showing what textbox to change?

Comment: I have several buttons. they have a class. When they are clicked it calls a function. But i want button one when clicked to only apply the result of the function to textbox1. I want to call same function each time button is clicked but send the 1 2 or 3 to it so it acts on the respective textbox.